# Sequentially number files by being prompted for the first number in php

Tags: php, windows, command-line, filenames

*php, command line, windows.*

I need to sequentially number each **.txt** file in a directory. Any way I can specify the **first number to use** in the sequence in the command line when I type the script? (Instead of every time manually editing the script itself).

Or instead (even better) being **prompted** to enter the first number **twice** (for confirmation)?

Like, in command line ("285603" is just an example number):

```
c:\a\b\currentworkingdir>php c:\scripts\number.php 285603
```

or (even better)

```
c:\a\b\currentworkingdir>php c:\scripts\number.php
c:\a\b\currentworkingdir>Enter first number: 
c:\a\b\currentworkingdir>Re-enter first number:
```

The numbering script:

```
<?php
$dir = opendir('.');
// i want to enter this number OR being prompted for it to enter twice in the command line 
$i = 285603;
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if (strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'txt')
    { 
        $newName = $i . '.txt';
        rename($file, $newName);
        $i++;
    }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Any hints please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$argv` variable. It is an array with a first element indicating script file name and next elements are arguments passed.
Given you type `php script.php 1234` in the console, `$argv` variable is as follows:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "script.php"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "1234"
}
```

---

**EDIT**: Your code should be like below:

```
<?php
# CONFIRMATION
echo 'Are you sure you want to do this [y/N]';
$confirmation = trim(fgets( STDIN));
if ($confirmation !== 'y') {
   exit (0);
}

$dir = opendir('.');
$i = $argv[1];
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dir)))
{
    if (strtolower(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == 'txt')
    { 
        $newName = $i . '.txt';
        rename($file, $newName);
        $i++;
    }
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Comment: thanks! i am a novice to php. do i insert this into my numbering script? or create a new script with it and place into the same numbering-script dir? else? i normally have to number 5-20K files at once (if that makes a difference re scripting).

Comment: Just replace `$i = 285603;` with `$i = $argv[1];`.

Comment: `<?php
$dir = opendir('.');
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "numbering.php"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "$argv[1]"
}
$i = $argv[1];`
//Parse **error:** syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\scripts\numbering.php on line 3

Comment: beautiful! thanks! any way do double enter the number (for confirmation)?

Comment: Sure, check my answer. I added confirmation code at the beginning.

Comment: nice safety confirmation `[y/N]`, thanks, will keep in the code! any way to require to **actually re-type** the number a second time? or maybe enter as `$argv[2]`, like `>php c:\scripts\number.php 285603 285603`  and error message if the two numbers are not equal (i need to enter 6-7 digit numbers, so this would ensure that there is no mistyping before renaming everything)?

Comment: this is what i did to re-enter the number: `$confirmation = trim(fgets( STDIN));
if ($confirmation !== $argv[1]) {
   exit (0);
}` thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Command-line arguments are available to PHP in the global `$argv` array, [as described in the manual here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

This array contains the name of the script, followed by each proceeding argument. In your case, when you run:

```
php c:\scripts\number.php 285603
```

The argument **285603** will be available as the variable `$argv[1]`. You can replace your `$i` variable with this, and the script will work as intended.

Comment: thanks! if `$i = $argv[1];`, then what goes to  '[1]=>  string(6) "$argv[1]"'?